# Cannot create a DataRelation if Parent or Child Columns are not in a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am trying to create a data relation using 2 tables on a data set but this error appears, even when I already verified (using logs and using the visual studio dataset visualizer) that said tables and columns are indeed in the data set

```
subProductsDataset.Tables.Add(subProductsTable)
subProductsDataset.Tables.Item(0).TableName = "subProductsTable"
subProductsDataset.Tables.Add(productPrimesCopy)
subProductsDataset.Tables.Item(1).TableName = "productPrimesCopy"
subProductsDataset.Relations.Add("productPrimeRelation", subProductsTable.Columns(productSetIdItemCol), productPrimesCopy.Columns(productPrimeProductIdCol))
```

To confirm the tables where correctly being added I used logs

```
 Console.WriteLine(subProductsDataset.Tables(0).Columns(0).ColumnName)
 Console.WriteLine(subProductsTable.Columns(productSetIdItemCol).ColumnName)
 Console.WriteLine(subProductsDataset.Tables(1).Columns(1).ColumnName)
 Console.WriteLine(productPrimesCopy.Columns(productPrimeProductIdCol).ColumnName)
```

Which outputs

```
productSetIdItem
productSetIdItem
productPrimeProductId
productPrimeProductId
```

Also, this exact code (using other tables) is used in another module and its working perfectly there

Comment: You need to provide us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are only two reasons that this would occur: either something is corrupt or you have done something wrong. As corruption is rare and you haven't shown us all the relevant parts of what you have done, I'm guessing the latter. You should also provide the EXACT error message you receive.

Comment: One possible explanation is that `subProductsDataset.Tables(0)` and `subProductsTable` are not referring to the same `DataTable` object. That's easy to test using the debugger.